# Jquery checkbox function get ID based on biggest data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, checked

I'm having trouble finding the jquery checkbox function to get the ID based on the largest data. The selected data, of course, is clicked and checked, not unchecked.

[image]

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="id[]" data-id="001" data-weight="10" value="001"/> A (10 kg) <br>    
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="id[]" data-id="002" data-weight="20" value="002"/> B (20 kg) <br>    
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="id[]" data-id="003" data-weight="30" value="003"/> C (30 kg) <br>    
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="id[]" data-id="004" data-weight="40" value="004"/> D (40 kg) <br>    
<br>
<br>    
<div>Heaviest Weight</div>
<input type="text" id="getWeight">
<div>ID the Heaviest Weight</div>
<input type="text" id="getId"><br>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maximum = null;
  $(".checkbox").click(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('weight');
      maximum = (value > maximum) ? value : maximum;
      id = $(this).data('id');
    
      $('#getId').val(id);
      $('#getWeight').val(maximum);

  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/andreasdan/pen/MWvVypm

Comment: You'll need to 1. iterate over all the checkboxes when one is clicked, 2. check if the checkbox is checked before considering its value.  here: https://codepen.io/amir-s/pen/zYdWqML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping all `checked` checkbox, and compare each weight, every change of each checkbox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".checkbox").change(function(){
      
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox:checked");
    var maximum = 0;
    var maximumID = 0;
    
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      var value = $(checkbox).data('weight');
      if( value > maximum ){
        maximum = value;
        maximumID = $(checkbox).data('id');
      }
    });
    
    $('#getId').val(maximumID);
    $('#getWeight').val(maximum);
  });
    
});
```